# Pingdom API create check via curl

Tags: curl, pingdom

I am creating a pingdom check via api, however there seems like the http attributes are not getting accepted, not sure if I am missing something in the syntax. Here's the curl i used,

```
curl -X POST -u 'your@email:yourpassword' -H "app-key: app-key" -d 'name=new&type=http&port=443&host=www.mydomain.com' https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks
```

The check is getting created however the HTTPPort is still a default one. Can someone suggest any solution to fix.

---

When created via GUI, it allows to add a port for HTTP, following ig the get request for one of the checks created via GUI,

```
{"check":{"id":1915300,"name":"test123","resolution":1,"sendtoemail":true,"sendtosms":false,"sendtotwitter":false,"sendtoiphone":false,"sendtoandroid":false,"sendnotificationwhendown":4,"notifyagainevery":60,"notifywhenbackup":true,"created":1450100471,"use_legacy_notifications":true,"type":{"http":{"url":"\/","encryption":true,"port":443,"requestheaders":{"User-Agent":"Pingdom.com_bot_version_1.4_(http:\/\/www.pingdom.com\/)"}}},"hostname":"mydomain.com","contactids":[10383440,10233710],"ipv6":false,"status":"up","lasterrortime":1453959166,"lasttesttime":1456295446,"lastresponsetime":151,"alert_policy":1077635,"alert_policy_name":"Alert immediately","acktimeout":0,"autoresolve":0,"tags":[],"probe_filters":[]}}
```

Here Port 443 is assigned to HTTP type.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your are trying with `port=443`, and this 443 port is for ssl (https). You can not use it for http. Try with other ports and it should work for you.

> TCP port 443 is the standard TCP port that is used for website which
>   use SSL. When you go to a website which uses the https at the
>   beginning you are connecting to port 443

Comment: I have created few checks via GUI, take a look below for curl get requests,